# Exec format error while using grub customizer

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, error-handling

When I open Grub Customizer and it begins searching for the boot list it throws this error '/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig:/etc/grub.d/40_custom.odt:Exec format error'
The file has the shebang #! /bin/sh so what else could be causing this error?

Comment: The file should be a plain text file, not a `.odt`-file.

Comment: Ahh right got it